# I want to combine the objects in the array, how should I change them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

```js
const data = [
  {
    productId: 6,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    optionName: "13inch",
    optionPrice: 0,
    qty: 2,
  },
  {
    productId: 6,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    optionName: "15inch",
    optionPrice: 1000,
    qty: 1,
  },
]

const results = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (prev.productId === curr.productId) {
    ???
  }
  
}, []);
```

output

```js
  {
    productId: 6,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    option: [
      { optionName: "13inch", optionPrice: 0, qty: 2 },
      { optionName: "15inch", optionPrice: 1000, qty: 1 },
    ],
  },
```

If the productId is the same as the code above,

I want to remove the overlapping part of key:value, create an option object for the non-overlapping part, and create an array object for value.

I tried to solve it by using reduce, but it didn't go well, so I'm asking you a question.

Comment: what about `.filter`?

Comment: please fix your question in order to I add the answer, what you want is deep-object-merge, it has nothing to do with `reduce` or duplicates

Comment: My question is wrong. Let me correct the question. Thank you.

Comment: _it didn't go well_ is never a sufficiently detailed description of what happened when you tried.  Take your time to describe the problem in words, it will really help people understand what you are trying to do.  Furthermore, if you are so stuck that you barely have any code to show for your effort, then spend more time talking about what you do or do not understand about the task at hand.  Explain exactly where you are stuck and why.  Computers need everything explained too - so it's good practice to spell it all out for us in words.  Pseudocode is better than no code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will explain in more detail what kind of problems have occurred in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to convert array into object, and use `productId` as key:

```js
const data = [
  {
    productId: 6,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    optionName: "13inch",
    optionPrice: 0,
    qty: 2,
  },
  {
    productId: 6,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    optionName: "15inch",
    optionPrice: 1000,
    qty: 1,
  },
  {
    productId: 4,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    optionName: "15inch",
    optionPrice: 1000,
    qty: 1,
  },
]

const results = Object.values(data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if (prev[curr.productId])
  {
    const obj = prev[curr.productId];
    if (!obj.option)
    {
      obj.option = [];
      obj.option.push({optionName: obj.optionName, optionPrice: obj.optionPrice, qty: obj.qty});
      delete obj.optionName;
      delete obj.optionPrice;
      delete obj.qty;
    }
    
    prev[curr.productId].option.push({optionName: curr.optionName, optionPrice: curr.optionPrice, qty: curr.qty});
  }
  else
    prev[curr.productId] = Object.assign({}, curr);

  return prev;
  
}, {}));

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I couldn't sleep well after worrying about this for a week.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure, functional approach which won't mutate any part of your existing array data:

```js
function deduplicate (array) {
  const results = [];
  const idCache = new Set();

  for (const item of array) {
    // skip if we've already seen products with the same ID
    if (idCache.has(item.productId)) continue;
    idCache.add(item.productId);
    // get products with matching ID
    const items = array.filter(({productId}) => productId === item.productId);

    // if there were none, store the single product as-is and continue
    if (items.length === 0) {
      results.push({...item});
      continue;
    }

    // add initial product to others, preserving order
    items.unshift(item);
    const merged = {};

    for (const key of Object.keys(item)) {
      const values = items.map(item => item[key]);
      // if all the same value, set it on the merged object
      if (values.every(val => val === item[key])) merged[key] = item[key];
      else {
        // set to property on obj in "options" array
        for (const [idx, val] of values.entries()) {
          ((merged.options ??= [])[idx] ??= {})[key] = val;
        }
      }
    }

    results.push(merged);
  }

  return results;
}

const data = [
  {
    productId: 6,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    optionName: "13inch",
    optionPrice: 0,
    qty: 2,
  },
  {
    productId: 6,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    optionName: "15inch",
    optionPrice: 1000,
    qty: 1,
  },
  {
    productId: 5,
    productName: "pouch",
    productPrice: 29000,
    discountRate: 19,
    optionName: "15inch",
    optionPrice: 1000,
    qty: 1,
  },
];

const result = deduplicate(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way you can do it:

```js
const data = [   {     productId: 6,     productName: "pouch",     productPrice: 29000,     discountRate: 19,     optionName: "13inch",     optionPrice: 0,     qty: 2,   },   {     productId: 6,     productName: "pouch",     productPrice: 29000,     discountRate: 19,     optionName: "15inch",     optionPrice: 1000,     qty: 1,   },   {     productId: 4,     productName: "pouch",     productPrice: 29000,     discountRate: 19,     optionName: "15inch",     optionPrice: 1000,     qty: 1,   }, ],

      output = Object.entries(
          data.reduce(
              (prev,{productId,...r}) =>
              ({...prev, [productId]: Object.entries(r).reduce(
                  (acc,[key,value]) =>
                  ({...acc, [key]: prev[productId] && prev[productId][key] ?
                      prev[productId][key] === value ? 
                      value :
                      [prev[productId][key],value] :
                      value
                  }),{})
              }),{}
          )
      )
      .map(
          ([productId,obj]) =>
          ({
              productId, 
              ...Object.entries(obj).reduce(
                  (acc,[key,value]) =>
                  !Array.isArray(value) ? 
                  ({...acc, [key]:value}) : 
                  ({...acc, option:value.map(
                      (v,i) => 
                      acc["option"] ? 
                      ({...acc["option"][i], [key]: v}) :
                      ({[key]: v}))
                  }),
              {})
          })
       );

console.log(output);
```